# Are coffee's properties different enough from water's to cause increased spillage while walking?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, home-experiment, surface-tension, viscosity, density

I recently found [this article](http://www.mnn.com/food/beverages/stories/why-is-it-so-hard-to-walk-and-not-spill-your-coffee-physicists-have-the-answe), which describes how...

> It just so happens that the human stride has almost exactly the right frequency to drive the natural oscillations of coffee, when the fluid is in a typically sized coffee mug.

*Judging by appearance*, coffee and water's fluid dynamics seem rather similar. Unfortunately,they do not site a source, but they mention that the study was done by "a pair of fluid physicists at the University of California at Santa Barbara (UCSB)".

My question is **how different are the properties of water and coffee? Is this difference significant enough to cause a dramatic change in how either fluid behaves in a mug (while walking)?**

**EDIT**: [Here](http://pre.aps.org/pdf/PRE/v85/i4/e046117) is the actual published article.

Comment: Without a whit of evidence I would suspect surface tension or viscosity before density. *// and "Go, Gauchos!  //// spent a little time at U Can Study Buzzed*

Comment: Your quote isn't really about coffee in particular - water (or orange juice, or tea...) in a coffee mug would [slosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slosh_dynamics) in just the same way as coffee does.

Comment: @poorsod, the article (and quote) only mentions coffee, and specifically coffee. I would imagine if the human stride has almost exactly the right frequency to drive the natural oscillations of water, among other things, they would have specified, no?

Comment: @LanceLafontaine Not necessarily. That has the smell of a "fun" paper, and coffee may have been used because it let them write an amusing story for publication in a serious venue. That kind of things gets people's attention. Think [Alpher, Bethe, Gamow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpher%E2%80%93Bethe%E2%80%93Gamow_paper).

Comment: Here's a link to a link to the the paper: http://physics.aps.org/synopsis-for/10.1103/PhysRevE.85.046117 Behind a paywall I'm afraid. *::sets browser to proxy through the local university, reloads, downloads, unsets proxy::*

Comment: I do certainly agree about the "fun paper". The actual report only concerns itself with coffee as well. Does that mean that water exhibits the exact same effect as described for coffee? Anyhow, excited to see an answer.

Comment: Hm, it appears the experiment itself involved coffee. I'd have expected it to have been run with water. I really do doubt there's any dynamical difference between coffee and water, though. Hopefully someone who knows more about this stuff will answer

Comment: the proper link is http://www.engineering.ucsb.edu/~rkrechet-lab/files/publications/pre2012.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The article's preprint

> Mayer H. C., Krechetnikov R. "Walking with coffee: why does it spill?," Phys. Rev. E 85, 046117 (2012).

is available from the [UCSB site.](http://engineering.ucsb.edu/~rkrechet-lab/files/publications/)

From a glance of the article the phenomenon is not specific only to coffee. The authors make use of the next formula:

> The natural frequencies of oscillations of a frictionless,
>   vorticity-free, and incompressible liquid in an upright cylindrical
>   container (cup) with a free liquid surface are well known from liquid
>   sloshing engineering:

$$\omega_{mn}^2 = \frac{g \epsilon_{mn}}{R} \tanh\left(\epsilon_{mn} \frac{H}{R} \right) \left[1 +\frac{\sigma}{\rho g} \left( \frac{\epsilon_{mn}}{R} \right)^2 \right]$$

$H$ is the liquid height, $R$ is the cup radius, $\rho$ is the liquid density, $\sigma$ is its surface tension, $g$ is thethe gravity acceleration. $\epsilon_{mn}$ are coefficients connected to Bessel functions.

The only parameter that can be significantly different between water and coffee is surface tension $\sigma$, but then the authors rule it out:

> For a typical common size of a coffee cup, $R$ $3.5$ cm and $H$ $10$ cm, which
>   is studied here, the surface tension $\sigma$ effect is negligible.

That is their calculations are applicable both to water and coffee. Their work seems to be all about biomechanics, the way human moves with unwanted frequencies.

Comment: Exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thanks, _1.